# How to get year and week number aligned for a date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While trying to get year and week number of a range of dates spanning multiple years, I am getting into some issues with the start/end of the year.

I understand the logic for `weeknumber` and the one of `year` when they run separately. However, when they are combined, in some cases they don't bring consistent results and I was wondering what is the best way in Spark to make sure that those scenarios are handled with a consistent year for the given weeknumber,

For example, running:

```scala
spark.sql("select year('2017-01-01') as year, weekofyear('2017-01-01') as weeknumber").show(false)
```

outputs:

```
+----+----------+
|year|weeknumber|
+----+----------+
|2017|52        |
+----+----------+
```

But the wanted output would be:

```
+----+----------+
|year|weeknumber|
+----+----------+
|2016|52        |
+----+----------+
```

and running:

```scala
spark.sql("select year('2018-12-31') as year, weekofyear('2018-12-31') as weeknumber").show(false)
```

produces:

```
+----+----------+
|year|weeknumber|
+----+----------+
|2018|1         |
+----+----------+
```

But what is expected is:

```
+----+----------+
|year|weeknumber|
+----+----------+
|2019|1         |
+----+----------+
```

Code is running on Spark 2.4.2.

Comment: This looks correct to me. Why do you expect this output?
weeknumbers are weird. Sometimes the first weeknumber starts in the previous year, and sometimes only halfway into the first week.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This spark behavior is consistent with the `ISO 8601` definition. You can not change it. However there is a workaround I could think of.

You can first determine `dayOfWeek`, and if it is less than 4, you increase the year by one, if it equals to 4 then keep the year untouched. Otherwise decrease the year by one.

Example with `2017-01-01`

```
sql("select case when date_format('2017-01-01', 'u') < 4 then year('2017-01-01')+1 when date_format('2017-01-01', 'u') = 4 then year('2017-01-01') else year('2017-01-01')- 1 end as year, weekofyear('2017-01-01') as weeknumber, date_format('2017-01-01', 'u') as dayOfWeek").show(false)

+----+----------+---------+
|year|weeknumber|dayOfWeek|
+----+----------+---------+
|2016|52        |7        |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Example with `2018-12-31`

```
sql("select case when date_format('2018-12-31', 'u') < 4 then year('2018-12-31')+1 when date_format('2018-12-31', 'u') = 4 then year('2018-12-31') else year('2018-12-31')- 1 end as year, weekofyear('2018-12-31') as weeknumber, date_format('2018-12-31', 'u') as dayOfWeek").show(false)

+----+----------+---------+
|year|weeknumber|dayOfWeek|
+----+----------+---------+
|2019|1         |1        |
+----+----------+---------+
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. One clarification: What is 'u'? I cannot find it in this [Spark reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)?

Comment: date_format function supports all Java Date formats specified in DateTimeFormatter class. Pls check out this link for more details -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @ShantanuKher  I'm trying to get the week of month out of a timestamp with date_format(dt_col, 'W') but it defaults to starting the week on Sunday, is there any way to change this to start on Monday instead? Im on spark 2.4

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = Seq(("2017-01-01"), ("2018-12-31")).toDF("dateval")

+----------+
|   dateval|
+----------+
|2017-01-01|
|2018-12-31|
+----------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("date_tab")

val newDF = spark.sql("""select dateval, 
                    case when weekofyear(dateval)=1 and month(dateval)=12 then struct((year(dateval)+1) as yr, weekofyear(dateval) as wk)
                         when weekofyear(dateval)=52 and month(dateval)=1 then struct((year(dateval)-1) as yr, weekofyear(dateval) as wk)
                         else struct((year(dateval)) as yr, weekofyear(dateval) as wk) end as week_struct
             from date_tab""");

newDF.select($"dateval", $"week_struct.yr", $"week_struct.wk").show()

+----------+----+---+
|   dateval|  yr| wk|
+----------+----+---+
|2017-01-01|2016| 52|
|2018-12-31|2019|  1|
+----------+----+---+
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the week of month out of a timestamp with date_format(dt_col, 'W') but it defaults to starting the week on Sunday, is there any way to change this to start on Monday instead? Im on spark 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a UDF to achieve this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields

def weekYear(date: java.sql.Date) : Option[Int] = {
     if(date == null) None
    else Some(date.toLocalDate.get(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR))
}
```

Register this udf as

```
spark.udf.register("yearOfWeek", weekYear _)
```

Result:-

```
scala> spark.sql("select yearOfWeek('2017-01-01') as year, WEEKOFYEAR('2017-01-01') as weeknumber").show(false)
+----+----------+
|year|weeknumber|
+----+----------+
|2016|52        |
+----+----------+
```